# Terraform detects changes to availability domain on data lookup

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-terraform

Terraform detects changes to availability_domain and forces a replacement when no change has taken place.

When I run `terraform apply` a second time with no changes made, terraform forces a replacement of my instance, this is due to the `availability_domain` lookup, is this a bug, or is my lookup incorrect?

```
  # module.services.oci_core_volume must be replaced
-/+ resource "oci_core_volume" "disk_res_instance[" {
      + auto_tuned_vpus_per_gb = (known after apply)
      ~ availability_domain    = "REGION" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      + backup_policy_id       = (known after apply)
      ~ freeform_tags          = {} -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                     = "ocid1.volume.oc1.me-jeddah-1.abc" -> (known after apply)
      ~ is_auto_tune_enabled   = false -> (known after apply)
      ~ is_hydrated            = true -> (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id             = (known after apply)
      ~ size_in_mbs            = "51200" -> (known after apply)
```

If I'm reading this correctly, it seems that the replacement is forced by the availability_domain, however, this remains unchanged.

```
resource "oci_core_volume" "diskinstance" {
  count               = 1
  availability_domain = data.oci_identity_availability_domains.ad_list.availability_domains[0]["name"]
...
```

**data**

```
data "oci_identity_availability_domains" "ad_list" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
}
```

Is it that each time the data look-up on the availability domains is being done it forces it to be replaced, or something else?

Comment: Did you run plan before second apply?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, yes, does that make a difference?

Comment: Could be, although it shouldn't make too much difference: https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources#data-resource-behavior.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is happening, tested with a static var and it no longer changes

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to Image as well. Check if you are pulling latest Image.

This would not be case if you are doing planning immediately

Note: once Instance is launched AD will not be changed for an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Image OCID could be the problem, I think terraform will be pulling latest image due to which terraform might be detecting difference.

Get the ImageOCID of existing instance and use the image OCID in variable. Reference variable to the instance resource.

Then try to plan and see if terraform detects the changes.

Else update your plan output.